# Get total points of user in MySQL Table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

[image: Table]

I have a MySQL table with the columns "user" and "warningpoints" for each warning as you can see in the table above. How can I get the user which has the most warningpoints in total in PHP?

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT t.user,sum(t.warningPoints) as sum_points
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.user
ORDER BY sum_points DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Or if there is only one record per person, no need to group :

```
SELECT t.user,t.warningPoints 
FROM YourTable t
ORDER BY t.warningPoints DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add below statements in your php code.

```
$sql = "SELECT User, Max(warningpoints) AS MaxWarningpoints FROM MyGuests GROUP BY User";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```